# WinNT Always authenticates Local User to True (NativeObject never faults)

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryentry

I've read that the below code is the way to authenticate a user against WinNT. I've been trying to authenticate a user on my local machine. For what ever reason, `root.NativeObject` never throws an exception whether my local user's password or username is correct or not. Any idea what could be the problem ?

```
try
{
  using (var root = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + _root, domainAndUsername, _password))
  {
     var root = root.NativeObject;
  }
}
catch
{
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to authenticate against Active-Directory (as your tags refered to) you can test :

```
try
{
  using (var root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://societe.fr/dc=societe,dc=fr", domainAndUsername, _password))
  {
     var root = root.NativeObject;
  }
}
catch
{
  return false;
}
```

You can use `WinNT` to add a local user (SAM) on a computer as shown here under, but in this case you are logged on this computer as an administrator.

```
DirectoryEntry deComputer = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://JPBASUSF1,computer");
DirectoryEntry deUser = deComputer.Children.Add("JPB", "user");
deUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { "test.2011" }); 
deUser.Properties["Description"].Add("user $userName");
deUser.Properties["userflags"].Add(512);
deUser.Properties["passwordExpired"].Add(1);
deUser.Properties["LoginScript"].Add("start.cmd");
deUser.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: Sorry about the confusion in the tags. I don't really know much about how windows user accounts work. I just wanted to know if it were possible to take a local user's credentials and authenticate them. It seems like what you're saying is root.NativeObject only works when authenticating a user against active directory. Right?

Comment: If you want to authenticate a local user you can use native API [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx). You can find many articles on how to use PInvoke to call native API in you C#. As far as the command line is concern you can use "RunAs".